# Correct use of "immature"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotation

I want to say that a technique is still in its early stages. Is it correct to say that such a technique is "immature"? Or is it bad practice to use "immature" in relation to nonliving objects/things?

Comment: It is common to use *immature* in this manner. It is also common to say that such a thing is *in its infancy*.

Answer (score 1):

*Immature* can certainly be used figuratively of nonliving things, although it originated in Latin as *immaturus*, a negation of *maturus*, meaning "ripe." Here is the entry for immature in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **immature** *adj* (1548) **1** *archaic* **:** PREMATURE **2 a :** lacking complete growth, differentiation, or development {*immature* fruits} {a sexually *immature* bird} **b :** having the potential capacity to attain a definite form or state: CRUDE, UNFINISHED {a vigorous but *immature* school of art} **c :** exhibiting less than an expected degree of maturity {emotionally *immature* adults}

Definition 2b is entirely on point for the context you describe. The only problem is that, as B Gaurav's answer indicates, definition 2c casts a rather large shadow on the word—and some people may take *immature* as a criticism along the lines of "inappropriately childish" or "developmentally slow" when it is used in the context of people or of intellectual efforts. That doesn't make using *immature* in sense 2b (or 2a) any less valid, but it does mean that at least one adjacent meaning in the neighborhood where it lives is not entirely friendly.

Consequently, phrases such as "not yet ripe" or "not yet fully ripe" may strike listeners or readers as less encumbered with negative implications than "immature." On the other hand, if you are describing something that is in a very early stage of development, you may be better off with a term such as *rudimentary* (in Merriam-Webster's sense of "very imperfectly developed"), *nascent* ("coming or having recently come into existence"), or (as Ian MacDonald suggests in a comment above) "still in its infancy."

Answer (score -2):

It would be better to use ***'seminal'*** or ***'formative'*** as adjectives to describe ***'early stage'***.

Immature is generally used in a sense that has a negative connotation.

Consider :

Its the work of an immature brain.

Comment: There are several things incorrect in this answer. _Seminal_ and _formative_ both mean quite different things from what is asked about here, and _immature_ does not necessarily have a negative connotation.